# Should I use which or whichever?

Tags: questions

I am confused between the following sentences.   Which of these sentences are correct?

> You wear whichever shoes are comfortable.
>
> You wear the shoes which are comfortable.

Please explain to me which sentence is correct.

Comment: The verb you are trying to use is _**wear**_. The verb _to wear_ is not related to the verb form _were_ in any way, although they sound similar. Please consult your dictionary to learn how to spell this simple English verb. Using your dictionary, especially where spelling is concerned, is very important to your progress in learning English.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both, they have slightly different meanings.  But your sentences aren't quite grammatical or natural-sounding.

> Wear whichever shoes are comfortable.

This means that the speaker is aware that the listener has a choice of shoes, and that the listener should choose the pair that is most comfortable.

> Wear shoes which are comfortable.

This means that the speaker is merely instructing the listener to wear comfortable shoes, without being aware of whether the listener actually owns shoes that fit that description or not.

In this usage, "whichever" implies a choice, "which" is a descriptor.

Comment: So same rules applicable for whatever,whoever,